# Access email inbox of email service

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I have a requirement where I need to send and receive emails in salesforce.  I created an inbound email service which generated an email address for my service to listen on.  I also created an organization wide email address and I want it to be the generated email address from the service.  Its something like my_email@2039487230948320948.apex.sandbox.com.  But in order to use the organization wide email address it has to be verified.  Is there a way to access the mailbox for that generated email address and click the verification link?

I'm trying to send emails with the from address set to the organization wide email.  I'm not able to do that until I verify it.  Generally I just want to be able to send an email from an apex service, and have another apex service listen for a response to that email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the email address from the email service directly, I would create an email address on your company mail server/service that forwards the mail to the email service address. You can change forwarding to yourself to confirm the email and then change it to point to the email service address.

And after rereading your question, it looks like you are using it almost as an integration? Email is not the best integration transport layer. If you are going from org to org, use APIs. If you are within the same org, just use Apex.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I know email isn't the best transport layer but unfortunately the org I'm working with doesn't have an API

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to forward incoming emails to you, verify the link, then change your code back to whatever it is you want it to do.

Comment: I updated the question to make my use case more clear